# Module Not Found Error in Python even though it is installed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am beginner in Python and am trying to use beautifulsoup module for web scraping. I have installed it using the command

```
pip install bs4
```

and

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

in my VScode Terminal as well as in Windows Cmd Prompt.
But when I run the file using

```
python3 main.py
```

it throws me an error saying bs4 module is not found.
I have attached the screenshot of the error.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdAoj.png)

VScode
Python 3.10 Application and
Python 3.10 Libraries folder are all added in my PATH too.

[PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Bjq.png)

I would love to get any help to solve this error. Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Hey. First thing is to create your Python and VS Code environments as part of your system variables. And then make sure that you add the modules lib folder in there too. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Hey. Please check the PATH picture.
PATH is having:
VScode bin
Python 3.10 App
Python 3.10 Lib Folder
All these 3

Comment: Flask and all is working fine, even others like tkinter,shutil, pytube and moviepy work